# sqlalchemy model creation failing due to missing required attribute - but it's not missing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an sql alchemy model that references another model as a foreign key.

```
class BaseMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kw):
        obj = cls(**kw)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, id):
        obj = db.session.query(cls).get(id)
        return obj

class Node(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    firsts = db.relationship('First', backref='node', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Node {self.label} {self.id}>'

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        

class First(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    node_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, label):

        if label is None:
            raise Exception("A first must have a label")

        node = db.session.query(Node).filter_by(label=label).first()

        if node is None:
            node = Node(label=label)
            node.create()

        self.node_id = node.id
```

Elsewhere in my code, I try to create a first with a brand new `label`, which seems like it should create a new `node` in the process and use it as a foreign key:

```
first = First(label=context.label)
first.create()
```

But I get the following error:

```
   File "models.py", line 12, in create
      obj = cls(**kw)
  TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
```

It seems to me that I am passing `label` to node when trying to create.  So why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

Firstly, the code initialises entities and then calls `create` on the instance.  This would result in *two* entities being initialised, since `create` creates a new entity.  `create` is a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod), so it can be called on the class directly.

Secondly, the `label` argument is not being passed to `create` where it is called, so you get the error when create calls `cls(**kw)`.

Instead of doing this

```py
first = First(label=some_label)
first.create()
```

do this

```py
first = First.create(label=some_label)
```

or just

```py
first = First(label=some_label)
db.session.add(first)
```

(note that `create` is also called in `First.__init__`).

Thirdly - and this more of a preference - I'd avoid calling `commit` in the `create` method. Commit once, at the end of the request. This is more efficient and avoids situations where some objects get committed but others don't due to an exception being raised part way through a request.